# Windows Store Apps: parsing large chunks of JSON

Tags: json, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have an application that connects to a REST API to retrieve some data in JSON format.

sometimes the response is in the form of large string.

what is the most efficient way to parse such a large chunk of data. I checked **DataContractJsonSerializer** but the parsing is not asynchronous.

is there another library or technique to parse large chunks asynchronously ?

Comment: Have you tried [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) ?

Comment: I checked the samples, it seems that parsing is not asynchronous

Comment: do it in another thread http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465290.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSON.NET.

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObjectAsync_1.htm

You can use it like:

```
var data = await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<ROOT_OBJECT>(stringData);
```